# Algebraic rules concerning the complex power function $z^\alpha$

Tags: complex-analysis

In Gamelin's Complex Analysis there is a discussion regarding the complex power function.

Let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary complex number. Define the power function $z^\alpha$ to be the multivalued function $$z^\alpha = e^{\alpha \ log(z)}$$
where $log(z) = log |z| + i Arg(z) + 2d\pi$ for $d\in \mathbb{Z}$. Letting $z = i$ and $\alpha = i$ we get $$i^i = e^{\frac{-\pi}{2}}e^{-2m\pi}$$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Similarly for $z = i$ and $\alpha = -i$ we obtain $$i^{-i} = e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-2k\pi}$$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Taking the product of both results we get, $$(i^i)(i^{-i}) = e^{2n\pi}$$ and for all $-\infty < n < \infty$ $$ e^{2n\pi} \neq i^0 = 1$$ and Gamelin points out that the usual algebraic rules do not apply to power functions when they are multivalued. What else, except that $(i^i)(i^{-i}) \neq i^0 = 1$, can be concluded about the algebraic rules of multivalued powerfunctions?

Of course it means that it is not always the case that $(z^a)(z^{-a}) = 1$ for arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{C}$. But am I missing something?

On a side note I realize I am not completely sure what is meant by 'multivalued'. Is it just that its multivalued because $z = x + iy$ where $x$ and $y$ can vary on $\mathbb{R}$, or is it because $\alpha$ is arbitrary? (Another example in the book states that when $\alpha$ is an integer, $z^{\alpha}$ is single-valued. Why?)

Thanks!

Comment: You should avoid the "multivalued" concept. $\log$ is an analytic group isomorphism $(\Bbb{C}^*, \times) \to (\Bbb{C}/2i\pi \Bbb{Z},+)$ whose inverse is $\exp : (\Bbb{C}/2i\pi \Bbb{Z},+) \to (\Bbb{C}^*, \times) $. Do you see how the multiplication by $a$ can be defined for $z \in \Bbb{C}/2i\pi \Bbb{Z}$ when $a$ is integer, rational, real, complex ?

Comment: Mixing different branches of the logarithm never leads to anything good. When you define $z^a\equiv e^{\log(z) a}$ then let $\log$ be *one* particular branch and you will have yourself a consistent definition for which $z^a z^{-a} = 1$ (and by fixing a particular branch I mean that you take $\log(z) = \log|z| + i\arg(z) + 2\pi ik$ for a fixed value of $k$).

Comment: @Winther, from what you are saying it seems like $z^\alpha$ is multivalued in the sense that it is not injective? And $z^\alpha$ is single-valued, when related to a particular branch of its local inverse,? Am I talking nonsense?

But even when we consider a particular branch of the logarithm, does the usual power rules hold? 

Thanks!!

Comment: @reuns, I don't understand what you mean, I have never heard of group isomorphisms, I googled the definition but can't really connect it to our discussion. And I also, what do you mean by multiplication by a?

Comment: @iaenstrom You are the one that gets to define $z^\alpha$ as a normal function. I'm arguing that if you need to define it for non-integer $\alpha$ then define it so that you only have one answer (i.e. choose a particular branch). It's like saying the square root of $4$ is $+2$ instead of $-2$. Both are equally valid, but when we define a square-root function we choose the former.